# personality issues - only mental?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As far as I can see from googling, the term "personality issues" mostly means a type of mental disorders.

Can it be, however, that in certain contexts (like jokes, for example, but not necesserally), it could stand for problems associated with relations between individuals (difference in character, incompatibility)?

Comment: Your title says 'personality issues', but your question asks about 'personal issues'; these have different meanings. Which one is it that you are asking about? Please edit your question or title.

Comment: Sorry, I'll correct it now. Personality issues.

Comment: One could argue that all personality disorders have a relational dimension to them. (Example: Oedipal complex. )his person might have what is jokingly referred to as "daddy issues.")

Comment: It's a little unclear how "problems with relations between individuals" relates to "jokes". Please elaborate. It might be helpful to provide some examples illustrating the link you have in mind.

Comment: A "personality issue" is not necessarily connected to a mental disorder. Someone may be hard to get along with, but is of sound mind.

Comment: Lawrence. I'm not sure, but I have some reasons to suspect that in the book I'm reading a character uses the phrase as a joke, Unfortunately, there's no immediate context to provide. It'd take reading the entire book to understand why I could think so.

Comment: @NoDa, why don't you give the title & author of the book, and a section of the text that includes the phrase? That's the way to avoid down and close votes.

Answer (score 2):

The term "personality issues" is often used as a kind explanation for differences of opinion that cannot be readily understood by one party. This can be a PC synonym for mental disorders and is used to describe such troubles without calling someone crazy or stupid.

As far as jokes if one does not understand or resents my humour it can be ascribed to *my* "personality issues" rather than *our* incompatibility which may be partly up to them.

Answer (score 2):

When you're trying to express problems between two people, you usually say they have a *personality conflict*.

You may even say "there are personality issues between X and Y", but you would not say that either one individually has a personality issue, unless you are suggesting that the individual has blameworthy character defects.